# Is it possible to inform TalkBack word pronunciation based on word type?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

Is there any sort of TalkBack screen reader markup to inform the TTS how to pronounce a word based on it's type? For example, 'read' pronounced in past or present tense? Or 'bass' being pronounced as a fish or musical instrument?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, depending on the type of widget you're using.  [`android:contentDescription`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps) might be what you're looking for.  But I would **not** recommend trying to force the screen reader to announce something a certain way.  If you want "read" announced as past tense and you have a `contentDescription` of "red", while that might *sound* correct when using a screen reader, it will not *read* correctly if using a Braille device.  The user will read "r e d" in Braille letters instead of "r e a d" and that will be confusing.